# How to have bootstrap fixed navbar not full width with banner on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am just getting started with bootstrap, and I need help setting up a navbar.

What I want ideally, is to have a top centered banner, and just below it a navbar. When the user scrolls below, the banner will scroll offscreen but the navbar will stick to the top. If the user scrolls all the way up again, the banner will reappear. For mobile users, they would have the icon on the right and when pressed will create a drop down menu.

The banner and the top navbar are not full width. The banner is 960px long, and I have it setup using `class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"`. Aesthetically it looks good this way for me.

I have seen a few posts on this topic, but none really mixing all these requirements together (not full width, sticking to top, and banner logo on top of navbar). I tried reverse engineering a few of the approaches but I have had no luck at all.

At the moment, I am just using pill boxes because it was easy to do and format for me. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Here is my code for what I currently have. I am happy with this setup, just would like the navbar to stick once it scrolls down. There are a lot of divs here as you will see, that I use for styling a page and shadows. Probably can be much more efficient, but as is it looks exactly like I want.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 rcshadow">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="../images/header.jpg">
                <!-- Fixed navbar -->
                <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-rc">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" /></span>&nbsp;Roll Call</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">&nbsp;New</span> <span class="glyphicon">Contact</span></a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" />&nbsp;Search<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact Search</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Quick Search</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">
                                            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                                                <div class="input-group input-group-xs">
                                                    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Search by name..." name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>                                        
                                    </a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" />&nbsp;Attendance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" />&nbsp;Planner</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" />&nbsp;Statistics</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" />&nbsp;Log-out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="rcpage">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h1>Test</h1>
                        <hr>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css file (besides the bootstrap):

```
/* set a max-width for horizontal fluid layout and make it centered */
.container-fluid {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 970px;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:verdana,arial,'sans serif';
    background-color:#3b607e;
    color:#000000;
}

.navbar-rc {
    margin-bottom:0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px;
    border-radius:0px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
    padding-top:5px !important; 
    padding-bottom:0 !important; 
    height: 30px; 
} 

.navbar-nav > li:hover, .navbar-header:hover {
    background-color:#e7e7e7;   
}

.navbar {
    min-height:30px !important;
}

.rcshadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}

.rcpage {
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:0px 30px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you scroll to the right position, you can adjust the navbar to have `position: fixed`. However, this will take it out of position in the DOM, so you'll need to adjust the width and placement, and account for the lost space by adding a margin to the container element. You might want to account for a few other things like taking out the border-radius like bootstrap normally would with `navbar-fixed-top`. It might actually be better just to add that class instead of setting `position:fixed`, but I ran into some other issues in my example, so it will take a bit of tweaking.

There's a bit of extra javascript in here to check the banner height rather than hardcoding it based on what it *should* be. It only checks when the page is resized, but this might need to be further tweaked (e.g. if you dynamically add elements on the page it could affect the height of the bar, or if a scrollbar gets added to the page to account for overflow).

I added ids to key parts of the navbar, but you could get them other ways as well (e.g. if you will only have one navbar you could just use `.navbar`.

I added `id="banner"` to your banner, and `id="navbar-container"` to the div containing it (which also contains the navbar). I added `id="navbar"` to the element with the `.navbar` class.

Then, here's a simplified version of the javascript, just to show the important bits. I've optimized it a bit though, which you can see in the full code snippet. For some reason the width seemed to be off by a pixel; I didn't really dig into why that is, but just added it back in when setting the width.

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
    var bannerHeight = $("#banner").outerHeight(true),
        shouldBeSticky = $(window).scrollTop() > bannerHeight,
        $container = $("#navbar-container"),
        $navbar = $("#navbar");

      if (shouldBeSticky) {
        var margin = parseInt($container.css("margin-bottom"), 10);
        $container.css("margin-bottom", margin + $navbar.outerHeight(true) + "px");
        $navbar.css({
          width: $navbar.outerWidth(true) + 1 + "px",
          left: $navbar.offset().left + "px",
          top: 0,
          position: "fixed"
        })
      } else {
        $container.css("margin-bottom", "");
        $navbar.css({
          width: "",
          left: "",
          top: "",
          position: ""
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var bannerHeight = 0,
    navbarHeight = 0,
    scrollTop = 0,
    isSticky = false,
    $container = $("#navbar-container"),
    $navbar = $("#navbar"),
    $banner = $("#banner"),
    $window = $(window);

  function setHeights() {
    bannerHeight = $banner.outerHeight(true);
    navbarHeight = $navbar.outerHeight(true);
  }

  function setScrollTop() {
    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  }

  function affixScrollbar() {
    if (!bannerHeight || !navbarHeight) setHeights();

    var shouldBeSticky = scrollTop > bannerHeight;
    if (shouldBeSticky !== isSticky) {
      if (isSticky = shouldBeSticky) {
        var margin = parseInt($container.css("margin-bottom"), 10),
          width = $navbar.outerWidth(true) + 1 + "px",
          left = $navbar.offset().left + "px";
        $container.css("margin-bottom", margin + navbarHeight + "px");
        $navbar.css({ width: width, left: left, top: 0, position: "fixed" });
      } else {
        $container.css("margin-bottom", "");
        $navbar.css({ width: "", left: "", top: "", position: "" });
      }
    }
  }

  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    setHeights();
    affixScrollbar();
  });

  $(document).on("scroll", function() {
    setScrollTop();
    affixScrollbar();
  });

  setHeights();
  setScrollTop();
  affixScrollbar();
});
```

```css
/* set a max-width for horizontal fluid layout and make it centered */

.container-fluid {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 970px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: verdana, arial, 'sans serif';
  background-color: #3b607e;
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-rc {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 5px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  height: 30px;
}
.navbar-nav > li:hover,
.navbar-header:hover {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar {
  min-height: 30px !important;
}
.rcshadow {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
  -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 10px #000;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}
.rcpage {
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 rcshadow">
      <div class="row" id="navbar-container">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="../images/header.jpg" id="banner">
        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-rc" id="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" /></span>&nbsp;Roll Call</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">&nbsp;New</span> <span class="glyphicon">Contact</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" />&nbsp;Search<b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Contact Search</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Quick Search</li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-xs">
                          <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Search by name..." name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                          <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" />&nbsp;Attendance</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" />&nbsp;Planner</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" />&nbsp;Statistics</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li>
                <a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" />&nbsp;Log-out</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="rcpage">
          <div class="row">
            <h1>Test</h1>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <p>Retro iPhone four dollar toast, synth Schlitz Austin cray typewriter Thundercats fashion axe fixie aesthetic bicycle rights. Bicycle rights taxidermy pickled tattooed. Kogi shabby chic Tumblr, Helvetica American Apparel raw denim chia before
            they sold out aesthetic bicycle rights taxidermy salvia paleo. Skateboard bespoke fanny pack, Godard hashtag put a bird on it yr vinyl sustainable tofu photo booth meh Thundercats forage. Street art 90's skateboard sartorial synth McSweeney's.
            Cornhole High Life twee tote bag, polaroid Pinterest listicle literally organic sartorial YOLO blog master cleanse 8-bit. Small batch Banksy wolf yr.</p>
          <p>Aesthetic cornhole lo-fi plaid, Odd Future seitan blog paleo. Ugh cronut aesthetic whatever photo booth PBR. Carles pop-up XOXO +1 readymade, meh health goth DIY. Chillwave Pitchfork kogi, Echo Park quinoa meggings fap asymmetrical Austin Wes
            Anderson butcher Neutra hella PBR mixtape. IPhone Bushwick wayfarers, organic ennui ethical flexitarian. Blue Bottle 8-bit single-origin coffee hashtag, Marfa mlkshk meggings literally pug YOLO. Small batch cliche literally, lumbersexual try-hard
            beard whatever Etsy umami skateboard tote bag Pitchfork.</p>
          <p>Street art YOLO scenester, irony tousled shabby chic crucifix roof party bitters gastropub you probably haven't heard of them. Keffiyeh before they sold out wolf typewriter DIY Thundercats. Keffiyeh banh mi meditation pug, leggings 3 wolf moon
            sriracha Blue Bottle. Swag ennui biodiesel, fashion axe mumblecore lomo sustainable lumbersexual American Apparel narwhal tofu Helvetica kitsch cred +1. Cronut squid keytar retro, chillwave ugh authentic synth semiotics distillery fingerstache
            bespoke Williamsburg. Helvetica chambray tote bag semiotics Godard fingerstache. Actually slow-carb artisan blog, deep v tote bag keytar pickled lomo Pitchfork biodiesel.</p>
          <p>Ethical Etsy drinking vinegar PBR&B Echo Park direct trade. Pug cronut ethical, you probably haven't heard of them Helvetica tousled mumblecore flexitarian before they sold out YOLO PBR&B dreamcatcher. XOXO craft beer sriracha, hella PBR&B polaroid
            Brooklyn Williamsburg banh mi biodiesel cray bicycle rights typewriter. Brunch vegan tousled, leggings hella chia deep v cold-pressed VHS. Jean shorts post-ironic authentic literally Shoreditch squid. Polaroid mixtape freegan, food truck Blue
            Bottle 90's umami. Craft beer Blue Bottle cliche, banjo polaroid keytar put a bird on it chillwave 90's.</p>
          <p>Four loko keffiyeh migas, kitsch High Life DIY chillwave farm-to-table banh mi gluten-free mixtape locavore. Flexitarian paleo photo booth fap, scenester mustache High Life organic small batch. Pug raw denim organic, biodiesel bicycle rights
            keytar mustache art party gentrify fingerstache ennui Williamsburg craft beer Brooklyn. Letterpress sustainable kogi squid cornhole. Semiotics disrupt pickled, kitsch XOXO scenester skateboard lumbersexual sustainable food truck pork belly
            crucifix Godard raw denim fixie. Pour-over master cleanse forage VHS, Thundercats disrupt pug Truffaut vegan quinoa keffiyeh Echo Park cardigan you probably haven't heard of them. Mumblecore leggings iPhone Blue Bottle, fashion axe street
            art chia Godard distillery shabby chic.</p>
          <p>Flexitarian Kickstarter migas, distillery jean shorts roof party cold-pressed lumbersexual. Asymmetrical 3 wolf moon Truffaut, Wes Anderson lo-fi hashtag PBR&B tousled Schlitz hoodie pug Williamsburg. American Apparel skateboard chambray Wes
            Anderson. Echo Park 90's Pitchfork Portland street art pop-up, flannel banh mi Godard VHS literally food truck. Semiotics butcher farm-to-table Etsy church-key Schlitz, tousled XOXO Vice street art selfies lumbersexual locavore. Cronut yr
            post-ironic plaid pop-up tattooed DIY master cleanse paleo, normcore scenester quinoa slow-carb. Neutra wolf jean shorts umami banjo fashion axe.</p>
          <p>Dreamcatcher migas artisan, iPhone tofu Austin food truck forage four dollar toast organic four loko gentrify Portland trust fund. Irony tilde mlkshk Neutra, gentrify organic pop-up next level photo booth. Austin Godard keffiyeh, plaid Tumblr
            vinyl meditation freegan direct trade mustache. Actually yr polaroid flexitarian banh mi. Sartorial cray Blue Bottle cred. Gluten-free YOLO post-ironic, craft beer Kickstarter American Apparel freegan. Marfa meggings tote bag biodiesel, umami
            migas kogi photo booth letterpress single-origin coffee Bushwick. Deep v organic readymade hashtag. Plaid mustache wolf irony leggings. Tilde occupy sustainable synth irony, readymade wolf normcore put a bird on it cliche. Cray fap cronut
            butcher, trust fund umami banh mi. Street art retro next level forage. Kogi fashion axe sriracha, biodiesel ugh cray roof party. Kogi keffiyeh occupy paleo bicycle rights, drinking vinegar tousled Portland.</p>
          <p>You probably haven't heard of them fanny pack street art pour-over, Wes Anderson 8-bit chambray mustache pork belly drinking vinegar. Bushwick health goth mumblecore keytar. 3 wolf moon direct trade put a bird on it twee tousled deep v, kogi
            iPhone meditation dreamcatcher lo-fi jean shorts. Church-key bitters vinyl narwhal lomo synth. Chambray literally flexitarian Marfa craft beer tilde. Synth small batch Portland 8-bit, American Apparel church-key disrupt skateboard brunch health
            goth listicle irony tofu artisan photo booth. Odd Future squid leggings paleo stumptown disrupt.</p>
          <p>Neutra Marfa McSweeney's asymmetrical Intelligentsia, wolf Brooklyn stumptown street art. Cardigan Intelligentsia viral, pickled crucifix forage wolf listicle normcore synth. Dreamcatcher keffiyeh cronut 90's, readymade sriracha fap mustache
            leggings Banksy Austin kale chips crucifix. Portland craft beer next level stumptown, heirloom four dollar toast tattooed McSweeney's hoodie shabby chic squid distillery before they sold out. Literally Tumblr ethical, cardigan 8-bit beard
            put a bird on it gastropub pour-over cornhole ugh lo-fi. Post-ironic shabby chic chillwave, semiotics salvia before they sold out flexitarian retro locavore distillery meditation letterpress cliche. Blue Bottle pork belly roof party Thundercats
            tattooed.
          </p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work for me. The banner would go offscreen and the navbar started full width. Even just making a new page with your code and adding my banner (using a simple img tag with only a source) would cause problems.

Comment: @DavidAvellan Could you update your question to show a working sample of what you already have? It would probably be a lot easier to tweak what you have than to start from scratch, especially since you already have the banner set up the way you like.

Comment: sorry about that. I just updated my post with what I have currently. Thanks!